# How to fix None return value from subprocess.check_output()?

Tags: python, regex, subprocess

My code scans the router for a mac address using a subprocess. But at startup, it returns "None". How can i fix this?

```
import re
import os
import subprocess

# MAC address regex
macRegex = re.compile("[0-9a-f]{2}([-:]?)[0-9a-f]{2}(\\1[0-9a-f]{2}){4}$")

cmd = "chcp 65001 && ipconfig | findstr /i \"Default Gateway\""
res = subprocess.check_output(cmd, shell=True, stderr=subprocess.DEVNULL, stdin=subprocess.DEVNULL)

def GetMacByIP():
 z = subprocess.check_output('arp -a ', shell=True, stderr=subprocess.DEVNULL, stdin=subprocess.DEVNULL)
 a = z.decode(encoding="cp866")
 f = a.find("Physical Address")
 o = a[f:].split(' ')
 for a in o:
  if macRegex.match(a):
     return a.replace('-', ':')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This part here:

```
def GetMacByIP():
 z = subprocess.check_output('arp -a ', shell=True, stderr=subprocess.DEVNULL, stdin=subprocess.DEVNULL)
 a = z.decode(encoding="cp866")
 f = a.find("Physical Address")
 o = a[f:].split(' ')
 for a in o:
  #print(a)
  #print(macRegex.match(a))
  if macRegex.match(a): # It's possible that this if statement never meets
     return a.replace('-', ':')
```

You have an `if` statement. When the condition never meets the statement, you didn't tell python what to return, and so, it returns `None`.

Comment: My attempts to revive this code were doomed to failure. Can you add the correct code? thx

Comment: I added some comments that might help.

Comment: In any case, I get return none. This is strange because in other interpreters (besides IDLE) the output is working. I just can’t understand why this is happening.

Comment: I know, but the print statements might give you a clue as to what's going on.

Comment: I tried to follow your prompts. When printing (a) is displayed, only a list of values appears - None, I still do not understand how this can help me. Can you provide a ready-made code with a solution, please?

Comment: Maybe change the if statement to `if re.findall("[0-9a-f]{2}([-:]?)[0-9a-f]{2}(\\1[0-9a-f]{2}){4}$",a):`?

Comment: That must mean there's something wrong with your regex string.

Comment: Hi again! Thanks for the help, it turns out the error was that the sublime and idle interpreters show console output in different languages. (In my case, IDLE showed in Russian), so findall could not even find it.